# Change css in a Bootbox window

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add styling (let's say bold attribute) to the "Hello world" in this code:

```
bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
   Example.show("Hello world callback");
});
```

Thank you

Comment: What does wrapping it inside `<b>` tags do?

Comment: you can't add styling to an alert. But what does example.show function do? Does this add markup somewhere?

Comment: @BenM it does work but I need to set the font size and more attribute, and I want to do this in an elegant way.

Comment: @JamieHutber you can ignore the Example.show(), thanks

Comment: Wrap inside a `div` with the proper `class` (so you won't pass all these stuff inside the string...): `bootbox.alert("<div class='label'>Hello world!</div>");`

Comment: @kambi I know this is an old question... but how did you get your show() to work? I cant get mine working (assuming this is the blue box that shows up after the alert is dismissed)... Could you please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do is to inspect the popup with firebug and you can see the HTML that makes up the modal window, so you can write css for it. Looking at the example on their website, here is the html that makes up a basic example:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;" tabindex="-1" class="bootbox modal fade in" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="modal-body">Hello world!</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary" data-handler="0">OK</a></div>
</div>
```

So if you wanted to change the footer colour:

```
.modal-footer {background:#c00;}
```

Answer (score 20):

Expanding on James King's answer:

using firebug's console you can see that the response to the command:

```
bootbox.alert('hello world')
```

is a reference to the bootbox containing div element; `Object[div.bootbox]`

So it's very easy to totally redefine the alert when you call it by simply changing its css attributes:

```
bootbox.alert('Danger!!' ).find('.modal-content').css({'background-color': '#f99', 'font-weight' : 'bold', color: '#F00', 'font-size': '2em', 'font-weight' : 'bold'} );
```

Answer (score 12):

Let's sum up:

**For styling text**

Add directly the html to your string:

```
bootbox.alert("<b>Hello world!<b>"); // (thanks BenM)
bootbox.alert("<div class='label'>Hello world!</div>"); // (thanks Adriano)
```

**For styling built-in bootbox elements**

Use the returning jQuery object to change classes, css, etc.:

```
var box = bootbox.alert("Hello world!");
box.find('.modal-content').css({'background-color': '#f99'}); // (thanks Mark B)
box.find(".btn-primary").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a 0 opacity empty div:

```
<div id="msgbox"></div>
```

then you can simple use a opacity change on js:

```
 bootbox.alert(x, function() { 
document.getElementById('msgbox').innerHTML = x; document.getElementById('msgbox').style.opacity= '1'; setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('msgbox').style.opacity = '0'; }, 2000);  });
```

and you can freely style the msgbox, with position, colors or even using some transition

```
#msgbox { color: #CC0000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; transition: all 1s linear; -webkit-transition: all 1s linear; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Asumming `Example.show();` is putting this code somewhere on the page, wrapping the element with strong will work:

```
 bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
   Example.show("<strong>Hello world</strong> callback");
 });
```

Comment: It wasn't me but I'll try to explain; `Example.show()` is part of the callback function so it only is called *after* the alert is shown and dismissed. Adding markup there only will be relevant for the call back function (whatever it does) and will not affect the markup on the alert shown